# write specific row only once?

Tags: python, csv, row

I want to write in a CSV file some data. I don't have a problem to do this. The only issue I get is that I want to write the "title" just once, but it's writing it every two lines.

Here is my code:

```
rows = [['IVE_PATH','FPS moyen','FPS max','FPS min','MEDIAN'],[str(listFps[k]),statistics.mean(numberList), max(numberList), min(numberList), statistics.median(numberList)]]

with open("C:\ProgramData\OutilTestObjets3D\MaquetteCB-2019\DataSet\doc.csv", 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    for row in rows:
        csv_writer.writerow(row)
k += 1
```

I want to have this:

```
['IVE_PATH','FPS moyen','FPS max','FPS min','MEDIAN']
```

written only once at the top of the file, and not every two lines.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is adding Not keywor in loop

```
with open("C:\ProgramData\OutilTestObjets3D\MaquetteCB-2019\DataSet\doc.csv", 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';') 
for row Not in rows: 
csv_writer.writerow(row) 
k += 1
```

Comment: Can u be more explicit please dear friend

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you opened the file in [append mode (`'a'`)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) and you are iterating over all the `rows` *each time* you write to the file. This means every time you write, you will add both the header and the data to the existing file.

The solution is to separate the writing of the header and the data rows.

One way is to check first if you are writing to an empty file with [tell()](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects), and if you are, that's the only time to write the header. Then proceed with iterating over all the rows *except* for the header.

```py
import csv

rows = [
    ['IVE_PATH','FPS moyen','FPS max','FPS min','MEDIAN'],  # header
    [1,2,3,4,5],                                            # sample data
    [6,7,8,9,0]                                             # sample data
]

with open("doc.csv", 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';')

    # Check if we are at the top of an empty file.
    # If yes, then write the header.
    # If no, then assume that the header was already written earlier.
    if csvfile.tell() == 0:
        csv_writer.writerow(rows[0])

    # Iterate over only the data, skip rows[0]
    for row in rows[1:]:
        csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

Another way is to check first if the output CSV file exists. If it does not exist yet, create it and write the header row. Then succeeding runs of your code should only append the data rows.

```py
import csv
import os

rows = [
    ['IVE_PATH','FPS moyen','FPS max','FPS min','MEDIAN'],  # header
    [1,2,3,4,5],                                            # sample data
    [6,7,8,9,0]                                             # sample data
]

csvpath = "doc.csv"

# If the output file does not exist yet, create it.
# Then write the header row.
if not os.path.exists(csvpath):
    with open(csvpath, "w") as csvfile:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';')
        csv_writer.writerow(rows[0])

with open(csvpath, 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';')

    # Iterate over only the data, skip rows[0]
    for row in rows[1:]:
        csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: its worked but the first line ( when the header should be is blank , do u know why ?

Comment: Does the *doc.csv* file already exist before you run the code? The only way I can reproduce an empty/blank is if *doc.csv* file already exists and it has empty/blank rows at the top. This will cause `csvfile.tell()` to return a non-zero value, so the header row is not written.

Comment: I've added an alternative solution that combines the creation of the file and the writing of the header row. If the file already exists, then succeeding runs of the code should only write the data rows.

Comment: When i use ur second way its gives me this result : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/skehal/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/new file.py", line 182, in <module>
    csv_writer.writerow(row)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Comment: Check the path you pass to `open` and the name of the file descriptor (`csvfile`)